# How can we find 404 pages on a website without google search console or conducting a crawl?

Tags: seo, 404, seo-audit

How can I find 404 error pages on a website to which I don't have access to conduct a crawl on or check google search console?

Comment: You don't usually need special access to do a crawl. Anybody can set up a crawler on any website.

Answer (score 2):

Check the server's "access log". This is really the main way to check for what URLs are being requested that are triggering 404s.

"Crawling a site" checks for broken (internal) links. GSC is reporting on internal links and backlinks.

(But if you "don't have access to [even] conduct a crawl on or check google search console", then maybe you don't have access to the server's "access log" either?!)